# I want to print the upper half of the butterfly pattern. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

[image: This pattern I want to print]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    for(int j=1;j<= 4;j++)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {if (i<=j)
            cout<<"* ";
            else if (i+j >= 9)
            cout<<"* ";
            else
            cout<<" ";
        }
            cout<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "butterfly pattern" and whether  the solution should depend on `n`.

Comment: You need two spaces in the last one. One extra space to align with the asterisks.

Comment: The problem is that you print only one space for the middle part, while the asterisk-pattern has the asterisk + the space. So the asterisk substring here has twice the size of the spacer substring.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer the question,

but here is a 2-liner for the above example ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb96628d7f7f8094)):

```
for (auto k : { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
     cout << string(k, '*') << string(8 - 2 * k, ' ') << string(k, '*') << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so when I deleted the extra space (in line 7) to be printed after the asterisk then the code worked fine but still, it should work just fine with space too!

Comment: If you want to keep the blank after the star, then you have to print two blanks `"  "` in the last `else`

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want solve this problem in C++ I have the perfect reference code for you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;
  cin>>x;
  x = 2*x;
  for(int i=0;i<=x/2-1;i++){

     for(int j=0;j<=x-1;j++){
 
        if (j <= i || j>=x-1-i )
        cout<<"*";
        else
        cout<<" ";
    }
    
   cout<<"\n";
 }
   return 0;
}
```